# How to handle a RemoveAbandonedQuestions post for a problem that still exits?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, automatic-deletion, abandoned-questions

I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38222385/getting-rid-of-the-return-element-in-nusoap-without-wsdl) that was closed `RemoveAbandonedQuestions` that is still relevant (A solution would be useful and can be useful to other people).

Is there a way to reopen in? Do I reask it?

(The main issues seem to be that this is related to relatively obscure versions of mostly obsolete software)

I have cast an undelete vote on the question.

Comment: improvements to the question is one way to prevent it from being deleted in this way, thus making it *not* abandoned and pushing it to the front page. But now you have to wait for undelete votes.

Comment: Nobody gets stuck on a problem for two years.  If you don't complete the Q+A yourself with the solution you ultimately used and did not think the problem was important enough to invest a bounty to attract more answers then there is no point in keeping it around.

Comment: @HansPassant: I have a workaround - I keep using the old(er) version for the affected part of the application, which is obviously not ideal

Comment: The system *very* rarely deletes questions of its own volition in this fashion.  If it hasn't had that much activity, I'm inclined to agree with Hans in that you didn't do enough to attract attention to it when it was still active.

Comment: I was considering a bounty, but spending half of my reputation (at that time) on a bounty did not seem worth it. (It is obscure enough that I might have just ended up losing the rep without getting an answer)

Comment: Yes, that's the risk with bounties.  You sacrifice reputation for the sake of visibility.

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions of improvements on that question? (On bounties: I have used bounties before with [unsatisfactory results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838563/gas-blob-upload-to-youtube-fails-for-most-files)). I'm not sure if what I'm asking is possible, and constantly giving all my reputation gains away without obtaining useful answers doesn't feel useful.

Comment: The fundamental problem seems to be that it is for a relatively low priority issue - A solution is useful, but not critical (I can use a non-ideal solution - publishing WSDL or staying on the ancient version) - on relatively obscure stuff (upgrading from a ~2004 version to the last ~2010 version of a deprecated library) seems to result in questions being deleted, irrespective of whether there are serious issues with them?

Comment: it gets deleted because it's inactive and no one has expressed any interest in it. It fits the description of an abandoned question. You didn't do anything that showed you still had any interest in an answer, so it was removed. The system can't read your mind, for all it knew you abandoned it and didn't care about it anymore.

Comment: @HansPassant Not to diminish your point, which I do agree with. I have many problems that I've been 'stuck' on for years. I don't have solutions but I do have workarounds. If I can I come back to them later sometimes years later. On SO that means editing my posts and answers. I typically put the workaround as the best current answer and improve it even years later. Of course this only works if your question is on topic.
Outside of SO being stuck on a problem for more than 2 years is sometimes called a PhD.